# Forwarding traffic from OpenVPN through Cloudflare WARP

Tags: openvpn, cloudflare, split-tunneling

I have an Ubuntu 22 node, and I'm trying new ideas to implement using Cloudflare WARP.
Let's say I want to have an OpenVPN server running on the node, while Cloudflare WARP is installed and connected. What I'm trying to do here is to forward all the traffic from the OpenVPN client through the WARP tunnel. At first I tried setting the WARP mode to Proxy mode and setting the system-wide proxy to that local proxy, but it didn't seem to be working. Then, I tried setting it to the WARP mode but having MY public IP address excluded so I can SSH into the server without any problems, and that works just fine. I even tried running an OpenVPN server and I could easily connect to it, but then the traffic wouldn't pass through the WARP tunnel (it would just stop working as soon as I connected my node to  WARP).

I wanna know if there's any way to implement this scenario, either with Proxy Mode or Warp Mode.

Thanks in advance.